# Can we read the newline CHR(10) or CHR(13) when reading dat in oracle /plsql?

Tags: oracle, file, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have to check in dat file if each line is correctly ended by CHR(10) and not CHR(13). If there is no CHR(10) at the 160 position or there is CHR(13) or other characters I need to raise an error.
I have used UTLFILE.GETLINE but unfortunately it is not reading the newline character. Any idea if this can be done on oracle?

```
Set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
V1 VARCHAR2(4000); --32767
F1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
last_char    VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
F1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR_IN_IMP_ACT_VENTE','temp.txt','R');
Loop
BEGIN
UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F1,V1);
dbms_output.put_line(V1);
dbms_output.put_line('Length'||length(V1));
-- Check if the line is not empty
    IF V1 IS NOT NULL THEN
      -- Get the last character of the line
      last_char := SUBSTR(V1, -1);

 

      -- Check if the last character is a line feed (CHR(10)) or a carriage return (CHR(13))
      IF last_char = CHR(10) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Line feed (LF) found at the end of the line');
      ELSIF last_char = CHR(13) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Carriage return (CR) found at the end of the line');
      ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No line feed or carriage return found at the end of the line');
      END IF;
    END IF;

 


EXCEPTION WHEN No_Data_Found THEN EXIT; END;
end loop;

 

IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F1) THEN
dbms_output.put_line('File is Open');
end if;

 

UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F1);
END;
/
```

Comment: Please note file should be encoded UTF8

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [utl_file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/UTL_FILE.html#GUID-9B839373-99A0-4B29-BE72-BF670B325245) says that get_line reads data up-to, bu not including, the line separator. So get_line will not help you there. You can use get_raw to get 160 bytes each time, and check for the 160 char. This would mean that all your 'lines' are 160 bytes including the line-separator.